# IOS 11: Hide TableView does not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, ios11, ios11.2

Hi I can't hide my table view using `[self.autocompleteTableView setHidden:YES];`, but It works on ios 10 but in ios 11 it's not hiding the table view.

Anybody could help me?

There's my code:

```
-(void) seachBarSetup{

self.autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.profileMapSearchBar.frame.origin.x, self.profileMapSearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.profileMapSearchBar.frame.size.height, self.profileMapSearchBar.bounds.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.profileMapSearchBar.bounds.size.height - 64) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

self.autocompleteTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
self.autocompleteTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
self.autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.autocompleteTableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = YES;
}

self.profileMapSearchBar.alpha = 0.8;
self.profileMapSearchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.autocompleteTableView];
[self.autocompleteTableView setHidden:YES];

self.profileMapSearchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.profileMapSearchBar sizeToFit];

 }
```

Comment: Please add the ViewController code. Without looking into the code it is difficult to speculate solutions.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar this is my VC code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `self.autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;` insted of `[self.autocompleteTableView setHidden:YES];`

OR

You will remove `tableview` from view by using this

```
[self.autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];
```

This will work.

Comment: I tried that two ways but It still not working :/ ... any idea?

Comment: Try this little thing. set alpha 0 of the tableview. `self.autocompleteTableView.alpha = 0;` knock me what is happen.

Comment: I found my error. The error was `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was called twice. Thanks a lot @FaysalAhmed